# glm::vec3 and epsilon comparison

Tags: opengl, glm-math

I want to check if a `glm::vec3` is equal to a zero vector `glm::vec3(0,0,0)`.

Until now I was writing

```
if(v == glm::vec3(0,0,0))
    ...
```

But then I learned about epsilon, so my question is if there's a faster (more readable) way to do this check than to explicitly compare like so:

```
if(abs(v.x) < EPSILON && abs(v.y) < EPSILON && abs(v.z) < EPSILON)
    ...
```

Comment: If you want to use an _epsilon comparison_ depend if you really want to test if the vector is _0_  or if you want to check a vector is close to _0_. Doing a correct _epsilon comparison_ is not trivial, and without knowing the exact use-case it is not possible to tell you.

Comment: I want to check if all the elements of the vector are equal to 0.

Comment: If you want to check if they are **exactly** _0_ then you won't need an epsilon test.

Comment: But if v.x is set to 0 then it might actually be something close to 0 in memory and then a ==0 test might fail. No?

Comment: If you do `v.x = 0.0f;`  then `v.x` is exactly zero, because zero can be represented as exact value.

Comment: I see. So I should use epsilon when compairing two nonzero vectors?

Comment: Depends ;). Sometimes you want to know if they are really equal and then you won't use an epsilon test. But in many situations you have two vectors that are a result of calculations and as of that you already have inaccuracies and then you often only want to test if they are nearly equal to each other and there you would use a test with epsilon.

Comment: What about a float that decreases over time until it reaches the desired 0.0 value? Should I use epsilon then? Also, can you answer my main question about avoiding the explicity x y z checks?

Comment: You know that the two comparisons are not testing for the same fact? The First one tests whether a vector is (0,0,0), the second one tests whether it is NOT (0,0,0).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A more readable (and maybe faster) way might be to use glms vector comparison methods:

```
if (glm::all(glm::lessThan(glm::abs(v), glm::vec3(EPSILON)))) ...
```

or one could compare the length (or the squared lengths, since this does not require a square root calculation) of the vector instead of the elements:

```
if (glm::length2(v) < EPSILON * EPSILON) ...
```

Answer (score 15):

You can also use glm's [epsilon comparison functions](https://glm.g-truc.net/0.9.4/api/a00146.html): epsilonEqual. They are declared in glm/gtc/epsilon.hpp